# Select columns into local variable from sql script using shell script

Tags: sql, shell, unix

How do I stores columns values retrieved from a table into a variable in my shell script.

I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

echo "This script will try to connect to sql plus and displays the date"
echo

sqlplus user/password << EOF
SELECT sysdate 
from dual;
EOF
exit;

echo "End of SQL"
```

I need to store the value of sysdate to a local variable and echo it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

```
    #!/usr/bin/ksh

clear

echo "This will print the Date"

VALUE=`sqlplus -silent apps/Z4vRD3me <<END
set pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off
select sysdate from dual 
exit;
END`


# xx=$(echo 'select sysdate from dual' | sqlplus -silent apps/Z4vRD3me)

echo $VALUE

echo "End of SQL"
```