# using SQL query on unix

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sqlplus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select columns into local variable from sql script using shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4130878/select-columns-into-local-variable-from-sql-script-using-shell-script)

im trying to write a unix script that will retrieve a parameter using sql query and run a script afterwards with this parameter.
for the time being, im just tryin to make it echo the retrieved parameter.
the sql query that works fine on toad (oracle 8) is :

```
select billcycle from bc_run
where billcycle not in (50,16)
and control_group_ind is null
and billseqno=6043
```

the above query give a number.

now the script i wrote is:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "this script will print the billcycle date"

v_bc=`sqlplus -s /@bscsprod <<EOF
select billcycle from bc_run
where billcycle not in (50,16)
and control_group_ind is null
and billseqno=6043`

echo "billcycle number is $v_bc"
```

the result when i run the file is

```
billcycle number is
```

with no number that follows.

any ideas what's wrong ? maybe the syntax for connecting to the sql server ?

thanks
Assaf.

Comment: What is the exact output of the sqlplus command run by itself?

Comment: Hi Joachim. the output is a 2 digit number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duplicate question APC linked to shows a working example, but to clarify you have two problems. The first is non-fatal and is just that you don't have `EOF`, as Rembunator pointed out <strike>(though it's in the wrong place in that answer)</strike>.

More importantly though you don't have a terminating `;` in your query, so SQL*Plus won't execute it - it just exits with no output.

If you typed your original query in as the SQL*Plus command prompt it would leave you at a further prompt waiting for input, and then go back to a normal prompt if you just hit return again, without actually executing the query:

```
SQL> select billcycle from bc_run
  2  where billcycle not in (50,16)
  3  and control_group_ind is null
  4  and billseqno=6043
  5
SQL>
```

You also probably want at least some formatting of the output. So this should work:

```
v_bc=`sqlplus -s /@bscsprod <<EOF
set pagesize 0
select billcycle from bc_run
where billcycle not in (50,16)
and control_group_ind is null
and billseqno=6043;
EOF`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should end with EOF as well:

```
v_bc=`sqlplus -s /@bscsprod <<EOF
select billcycle from bc_run
where billcycle not in (50,16)
and control_group_ind is null
and billseqno=6043
EOF`
```

Edited: Oops, as corrected by Alex Poole.